# Assembly code to draw a Square

Tags: assembly

I need a code in assembly to draw a square in middle of the screen.

Using BIOS video services, the resolution of the screen should be 320x200. The dimension’s length should be 20 pixels. The color of the square should be yellow with black background as shown below:

Answer (score 5):

The BIOS services have extremely high overhead and should never be used for plotting individual pixels.

For "mode 0x13" you can access display memory directly - it's 1 byte per pixel, starting at 0xA000:0x0000, where each horizontal line follows the previous horizontal line (no gaps/padding). For example:

```
    mov ax,0xA000
    mov es,ax
    xor di,di           ;es:di = address of top left pixel
```

To fill the top line of the screen you need to set 320 bytes (pixels) to zero. So:

```
    mov ax,0xA000
    mov es,ax
    xor di,di             ;es:di = address of top left pixel

    xor ax,ax             ;al = ah = black
    mov cx,320/2          ;cx = number of pairs of pixels to set
    cld                   ;Set direction to make sure
    rep stosw             ;Set entire line to black
```

Now, you're going to want many lines at the top set to black, so:

```
    mov ax,0xA000
    mov es,ax
    xor di,di             ;es:di = address of top left pixel

;Do top lines

    mov bx,(200-BOX_Y)/2  ;bx = number of lines at top to make black
    xor ax,ax             ;al = ah = black
.topLoop:
    mov cx,320/2          ;cx = number of pairs of pixels to set
    cld                   ;Set direction to make sure
    rep stosw             ;Set entire line to black
    sub bx,1              ;bx = number of lines left to do
    jne .topLoop          ;Do next line if there are more lines to do
```

The next part is the box itself. For each line where the box is you want some black pixels on the left, some yellow pixels in the middle and some more black pixels on the right:

```
;Do middle lines

    mov bx,BOX_Y          ;bx = number of lines in middle
.middleLoop:
    mov cx,(320-BOX_X)/2  ;cx = number of pixels to set
    rep stosb             ;Set left black
    mov cx,BOX_X
    mov al,BOX_COLOUR     ;al = box colour
    rep stosb             ;Set middle coloured part
    mov cx,320-(320-BOX_X)/2 - BOX_X
    xor al,al             ;al = black
    rep stosb             ;Set right black part
    sub bx,1              ;bx = number of lines left to do
    jne .middleLoop       ;Do next line if there are more lines to do
```

Finally, you'd want to set the bottom lines to black too. This is like doing the top lines. The complete piece of code ends up like this:

```
    mov ax,0xA000
    mov es,ax
    xor di,di             ;es:di = address of top left pixel

;Do top lines

    mov bx,(200-BOX_Y)/2  ;bx = number of lines at top to make black
    xor ax,ax             ;al = ah = black
.topLoop:
    mov cx,320/2          ;cx = number of pairs of pixels to set
    cld                   ;Set direction to make sure
    rep stosw             ;Set entire line to black
    sub bx,1              ;bx = number of lines left to do
    jne .topLoop          ;Do next line if there are more lines to do

;Do middle lines

    mov bx,BOX_Y          ;bx = number of lines in middle
.middleLoop:
    mov cx,(320-BOX_X)/2  ;cx = number of pixels to set
    rep stosb             ;Set left black
    mov cx,BOX_X
    mov al,BOX_COLOUR     ;al = box colour
    rep stosb             ;Set middle coloured part
    mov cx,320-(320-BOX_X)/2 - BOX_X
    xor al,al             ;al = black
    rep stosb             ;Set right black part
    sub bx,1              ;bx = number of lines left to do
    jne .middleLoop       ;Do next line if there are more lines to do

;Do bottom lines

    mov bx,200 - BOX_Y - (200-BOX_Y)/2
    xor ax,ax             ;al = ah = black
.bottomLoop:
    mov cx,320/2          ;cx = number of pairs of pixels to set
    rep stosw             ;Set entire line to black
    sub bx,1              ;bx = number of lines left to do
    jne .bottomLoop       ;Do next line if there are more lines to do
```

*Notes: All code above is intended for NASM (different assemblers can be different); and none of it was tested at all. I have assumed you're in real mode. You will need to define some constants to get it to work (`BOX_X`, `BOX_Y` and `BOX_COLOUR`). It can be done more efficiently in various cases. I didn't bother with whatever calling conventions you're using, or pushing and popping modified registers, or doing a `ret`. I have assumed that 0x00 is black (and was too lazy to guess what the value of yellow is); and this may be wrong (how values are mapped to colours depends on how you felt like setting the palette, so any value can be any colour and 0x00 might be bright pink or anything else and not black)*

Comment: Bloody hell, this takes me back! I've still got a 1000+ page EGA & VGA programming guide gathering dust somewhere.

Comment: The (4-time appearing) code: `mov ax,0xA0000` `mov es,ax` is wrong! The correct segment is 0xA000. One can only hope the OP and the 6k other users were smart enough to autocorrect this in the past 9 years.

Comment: The "top loop" and "bottom loop" don't really need to be loops at all, just multiply (at build time) the constants you were putting in `bx` and `cx` and run a single `rep stosw`.

Comment: The bottom loop still initialises `es:di` wrongly but I'm not sure how to correct that (as opposed to the wrong value in `ax` which I edited).

Comment: @ecm: In general my goal (when writing example code) is to create an example other people can use to learn how to write their own code themselves. It's the main reason for the note - both the "none of it was tested at all" and the "it can be done more efficiently in various cases".  If people want actual production code that can be cut & pasted without learning anything, I expect payment.

Comment: @ecm "...initialises `es:di` wrongly but I'm not sure how to correct that..." Similar to how the *middleloop* uses the last DI from the *toploop*, should the *bottomloop* use the last DI from the *middleloop*. The code does not need to initialize either ES or DI prior to the *bottomloop*. If none of the users of this code ever noticed this error it's probably because the screen was already black from setting up the screen mode and the *bottomloop* just repainted the top lines (black over black).